# Why declare a va_list inside a for loop?

Tags: c

The following code is from better string library header.
While looking at the define macros, I notice that va_list, va_start, and va_end are all used inside the for loop.

Wonder why this is necessary?

By the way, I have looked into the function bvcformata which doesn't modify bstrmp_arglist.

```
#define bvformata(ret, b, fmt, lastarg) { \
        bstring bstrtmp_b = (b); \
        const char * bstrtmp_fmt = (fmt); \
        int bstrtmp_r = BSTR_ERR, bstrtmp_sz = 16; \
        for (;;) { \
                va_list bstrtmp_arglist; \
                va_start (bstrtmp_arglist, lastarg); \
                bstrtmp_r = bvcformata (bstrtmp_b, bstrtmp_sz, bstrtmp_fmt, bstrtmp_arglist); \
                va_end (bstrtmp_arglist); \
                if (bstrtmp_r >= 0) { /* Everything went ok */ \
                        bstrtmp_r = BSTR_OK; \
                        break; \
                } else if (-bstrtmp_r <= bstrtmp_sz) { /* A real error? */ \
                        bstrtmp_r = BSTR_ERR; \
                        break; \
                } \
                bstrtmp_sz = -bstrtmp_r; /* Doubled or target size */ \
        } \
        ret = bstrtmp_r; \
}

#endif
```

Could the va_list, va_start, and va_end be "moved" out of the for loop? I am still a beginner in C. Just wondering why they have to be used inside the for loop?

```
#define bvformata(ret, b, fmt, lastarg) { \
        bstring bstrtmp_b = (b); \
        const char * bstrtmp_fmt = (fmt); \
        int bstrtmp_r = BSTR_ERR, bstrtmp_sz = 16; \
        va_list bstrtmp_arglist; \             <--------*****
        va_start (bstrtmp_arglist, lastarg); \ <--------*****
        for (;;) { \
                bstrtmp_r = bvcformata (bstrtmp_b, bstrtmp_sz, bstrtmp_fmt, bstrtmp_arglist); \
                
                if (bstrtmp_r >= 0) { /* Everything went ok */ \
                        bstrtmp_r = BSTR_OK; \
                        break; \
                } else if (-bstrtmp_r <= bstrtmp_sz) { /* A real error? */ \
                        bstrtmp_r = BSTR_ERR; \
                        break; \
                } \
                bstrtmp_sz = -bstrtmp_r; /* Doubled or target size */ \
        } \
        va_end (bstrtmp_arglist); \ <--------*****
        ret = bstrtmp_r; \
}

#endif
```

Comment: If `va_list` is a pointer, I don't think there is any guarantee that `va_arg()` would not dereference the pointer and modify the contents.

Comment: if I see this kind of macro in our company code I will force the author to write 1000 times on the blackboard "I will never write something like this again" https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Zdr.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `va_list` declaration outside the loop. But `va_start` and `va_end` have to stay in the loop, so that each call to `bvcformata()` will process the variable arguments from the beginning again.

```
#define bvformata(ret, b, fmt, lastarg) { \
        bstring bstrtmp_b = (b); \
        const char * bstrtmp_fmt = (fmt); \
        int bstrtmp_r = BSTR_ERR, bstrtmp_sz = 16; \
        va_list bstrtmp_arglist; \
        for (;;) { \
                va_start (bstrtmp_arglist, lastarg); \
                bstrtmp_r = bvcformata (bstrtmp_b, bstrtmp_sz, bstrtmp_fmt, bstrtmp_arglist); \
                va_end (bstrtmp_arglist); \
                if (bstrtmp_r >= 0) { /* Everything went ok */ \
                        bstrtmp_r = BSTR_OK; \
                        break; \
                } else if (-bstrtmp_r <= bstrtmp_sz) { /* A real error? */ \
                        bstrtmp_r = BSTR_ERR; \
                        break; \
                } \
                bstrtmp_sz = -bstrtmp_r; /* Doubled or target size */ \
        } \
        ret = bstrtmp_r; \
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind silly me. I just notice that there are "break"s within the for loop. By "moving" the va_list and va_end out will create a memory leak.

Comment: Why do you think so? Your updated code calls `va_end` outside the loop.